# TFS - Multiple builds feeding a single release

Tags: tfs, build, artifact

I have 2 builds (A & B), which create their own artifacts which are dropped into the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and then published to 'Visual Studio Team Services/TFS'

Everything works fine for build A, but I am finding that when I am wanting to download an artifact from build B, that artifact cannot be found. When I look at the error message, I can see that TFS is actually looking for it from build A.

I dont want to point to a specific build number for build B, instead just want to point to the latest build of B.

Anyone know how I can update the reference so that TFS is looking at build B?

[image: Trigger New Release]

If I use the 'Download Artifact' Task, I can get this to work if I point to a 'Specific Build', but it does not work if I use the option 'Current Build'

[image: Download Artifact]

Comment: How did you set the release definition? Generally you just need to link multiple sources (Build definition A and B here) as the artifacts.

Comment: Yes, we have 2 artifacts set up for the release definition already but what we see is that the release is only referencing a single artifact

Comment: Is Build B actually publishing an artifact? Are there files being uploaded?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Yes artifacts are being published by both builds

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps to achieve that:

1. Create 2 build definitions to queue Build A and B :

   Build Definition A -- Build A

   Build Definition B -- Build B
2. Create a release definition, add `Build Definition A` and `Build Definition B` as the artifacts source.
3. Trigger the release

[image]

---

Release works with multiple artifacts:

[image]

---

**UPDATE1:**

The `Download Artifact` task only works on single artifact, multiple artifacts doesn't work.

Besides, why you have to use the `Download Artifact` task?  By default the release definition has enabled the `Download Artifact`, that means it will download the multiple artifacts automatically, then you just need to use the multiple artifacts directly in other tasks.

---

**UPDATE2:**

Since you already linked multiple artifacts in your release definition, that means you have to download them to use on subsequent Phases/tasks. But based on your description seems you want to use the `Download Artifact` task to down the latest version of one of them. That seems a bit contradictory for your requirements.

I can think of  is that you can download the artifacts to a **staging folder**, then add copy task to copy the artifacts which you need in your phases.

Besides if you want to download all the latest artifacts, you can try this extension: [Download Artifacts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chamindac.chamindac-vsts-release-task-download-artifacts)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. We already have the builds linked to the release in the Pipeline, but we get the following error when trying to download the artifact (from build B): "Artifact drop not found for build 5149" but build 5149 was actually for Definition A

Comment: @Richard.Gale Just for troubleshooting, please try to remove Build definition A from the Artifact source, keep linking Build B only in your release definition, then check if that works for build B. You can also try to Mark build definition B as primary then check what happens.

Comment: We just tried updating Build Definition B to be Primary, now all other Artifact downloads (Which are looking for Definition A) are failing as they are looking at Definition B. (i.e Artifact ConfigurationScripts not found for build 13294) Build 13294 is Definition B

Comment: @Richard.Gale Could you please share the configuration of your release definition? Cannot reproduce your issue, everything works on my side.

Comment: I have added an image to show the Artifacts that are referenced when triggering a new Release. Our releases do not trigger a build, we are fine with triggering builds only when something has changed.

Comment: It works fine if I use the 'DownloadArtifact' Task and point to a 'Specific Build'. But if I use 'Current Build' then the Artifact is not found. But I dont like using the Specific build option, as if there is a new build, we will continue to point at the old build - I have added another Image to show how I have it configured at the moment. Can I use a wildcard in the 'Build' field so it always takes the Latest?

Comment: @Richard.Gale The `Download Artifact` task only works on single artifact, multiple artifacts doesn't work. Besides, why you have to use the `Download Artifact` task?  By default the release definition has enabled the `Download Artifact`, that means it will download the multiple artifacts automatically, then you just need to use the multiple artifacts directly in other tasks.

Comment: We have used the Download Artifact task because we have a large number of Artifacts produced by our builds, so we are using the Download Artifact Task to ensure we are only downloading the artifacts that are required for that phase, otherwise our release would take a lot longer to deploy.

Comment: @Richard.Gale Unfortunately it cannot achieve your requirements by the `Download Artifact` task, just I said above, the task will not work for multiple artifacts. It only against the single build artifact. Or make it work using the `specific build` as you mentioned, but the CI/CD will not work...

Comment: Thanks for your time on this @Andy Li-MSFT. We are going with the the specific build approach for now until we find a better solution

Comment: @Richard.Gale Since you already linked multiple artifacts in your release definition, that means you have to download them to use on subsequent Phases/tasks. But based on your description seems you want to use the `Download Artifact` task to down the latest version of one of them. That seems a bit contradictory for your requirements. I can think of  is that you can download the artifacts to a staging folder, then add copy task to copy the artifacts which you need in your phases.

Comment: What we were seeing was a huge slow down in each phase when the artifacts were being automatically downloaded, we saw a big difference in the running times if we set 'Skip Download of Artifacts' and instead used the 'Download Artifact' Task to get only the Artifacts we need for that phase. So its not that we particularly want to use that 'Download Artifact' task, but more that we saw much better running times using it, the only downside is that we can only set to a specific build ID rather than just saying use latest from Build B.

Comment: @Richard.Gale Yeah, I see, please see the updated answer, I think **staging folder** should be a workaround. BTW, if the answer helps, please vote it up and if that resolved your issue, you could accept it as an answer.